# What is the purpose of the 'tracking.live' MongoDB database?

Tags: xdb, aggregation

Sitecore XP version `8.0`, `8.1` and `8.2` comes with following MongoDB databases:

- `analytics`
- `tracking.live`
- `tracking.history`
- `tracking.contact`

What is the purpose of the `tracking.live` database in MongoDB?

Answer (score 11):

### Tracking Live

The `tracking.live` database is used by two entities:

- *Task Storage* (defined in `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.config` file)
- *Live Processing Pool* (defined in `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.ProcessingPools.config` file)

#### Task Storage

Works with the `TaskQueue` collection that is defined in the `tracking.live` database. Deferent Sitecore roles can add new tasks to collection and get tasks from collection. Task storage is used by the *Task Queue*. The queue is used by the *Task Manager*. The *Processing / Aggregation* role runs the *Task Agent* (defined in `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.config` file). The agent gets tasks from the *Task Manager* and executes them.

Tasks are added to queue by various parts of the system when processing of large amounts of data is necessary (removing contacts from automation states, setting timeout date of automation state, updating classification of location, etc). Custom code can also schedule tasks to be processed by the *Processing / Aggregation* role, which typically sits on a dedicated server.

#### Live Processing Pool

Works with the `ProcessingPool` collection that is defined in the `tracking.live` database too. Whenever a new session is flushed (on the `Session_End` event) to the `analytics` database, the `Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.CommitSession.ProcessingPoolAdd` processor (defined in the `submitSessionContext` pipeline) adds a new work item with an interaction ID to the live processing pool for the future processing.

The live processing pool is referenced by the *Live Interaction Aggregation Context* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.config` file), where the context is used by the *Interaction Aggregator* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file).

The *Processing / Aggregation* role runs the aggregator. It gets work items from the live processing pool through *Aggregation Context*. Each work item is processed by calling the `analytics.aggregation/interactions` pipeline.

The *Live Interaction Aggregation Context* is also referenced by the *Interaction Work Dispatcher* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file). The dispatcher is used by the *Aggregation Cleanup* and *Aggregation Recovery* agents (both defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file).